# How to assign a deployment to a node without changing other deployments

Tags: kubernetes

I have a case in my hand, my case is, I have a new deployment `(deployment A)` and this deployment should be assigned a specific node `(node X)`. It's fine and perfectly doable with `NodeSelector`, but I have other deployments `(deployment B,C,D)` in the same cluster too. Other deployment pods can be assigned to this specific node randomly because there is no restriction and/or extra configuration for them to not to.

How can I restrict this single deployment to this specific node without making any changes on other deployment configurations? Other deployment pods should not come to this node at the end of the day.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Please read about taints and tolerance. Tain your node to repel all other deployments/pods and add toleration to the pods, which can then be scheduled on that node. Refer - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1: Label the Desired Node**

Label the specific node (Node X) where you want Deployment A to run:

```
kubectl label nodes <node_name> deploymentA=true
```

Replace <node_name> with the name of the specific node (Node X).

**Step 2: Use Node Selector and Node Affinity for Deployment A**

In your Deployment A YAML configuration, specify the node selector and node affinity to ensure it runs only on the labeled node:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-A
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: deployment-A
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: deployment-A
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        deploymentA: "true"
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: deploymentA
                operator: In
                values:
                - "true"
      # rest of your deployment configuration
```

**Explanation:**

- nodeSelector ensures that pods of Deployment A are only scheduled on nodes that have the label deploymentA=true.
- nodeAffinity further enforces this constraint by specifying a required node selector term, ensuring that Deployment A pods are scheduled only on nodes with the specified label.

By doing this, you're isolating Deployment A to run exclusively on Node X without affecting the scheduling behavior of other deployments unless they have similar node selector or affinity rules defined in their configurations.